# how to auto refresh php  page with jquery 

Tags: php, jquery, session

as the question stated. everytime auto refresh 5s, its removing the session and give me the errors `Notice: undefined variables in get_total_un_booking and get_total_un_booking`.

before  tag ive got php include and classes:

```
session_start();
require_once '../_include/user.inc.php';
require_once '../_include/booking.inc.php';
$user= new user;
$booking = new booking;
$getUser = $user->getUser($_GET['id_user']);
$getBookslot = $booking->get_bookslot($_GET['b_ref']);
```

HTML Nav:

```
<table id="nav">
<tr>
  <td><? include 'pages/nav.php'; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

in Nav.php:

```
<? if($booking->get_total_un_booking() == 0) :
   echo '<a href="home.php?confirm"><span></span>Booking</a>';
?>
<? if($booking->get_total_un_booking() == 0) :
   echo '<a href="home.php?testimonial"><span></span>Confirm Testmnl</a>';
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function() {  
        $("#nav").load('pages/nav.php');  
   }, 5000);  
 });
```

Comment: What are you doing in 'settings.php'?, can you put some of the code as the work session or something to see if the problem is there

Comment: Does this happens in your first consultation Ajax?, Did you check the code to see if you have somewhere a 'session_destroy' or some file that you include?

Comment: ive made few changes on the code above! can u check! the session is fine! its jsut give me an error `Notice: undefined variable` everytime auto refresh with jquery. but if i F5 the page working fine! no errors!

Comment: What is the full code `pages/nav.php`?, only the code of this file without separating the html and php

Comment: @andres ive just added some more code on nav.php! its bascially just content navigation menu and few php function!

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to the session variables in pages/settings.php , you must call `session_start()` on that page.

Comment: ive called session_start() in every page!

Answer (score 0):

Does your browser allow Cookies?
I mean check your Browser configuration. And start the session handling on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can always transfer the session variable manually (presuming the JS comes from your PHP document):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function() {  
        $("#content").load('pages/setting.php?PHPSESSID=<?=session_id();?>');  
   }, 5000);  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses values from `_GET` array, but your `.load()` doesn't provide any - that's why there are `undefined variable`s

```
<?php
    $id_user = $_GET['id_user'];
    $b_ref = $_GET['b_ref'];
?>
$("#nav").load('pages/nav.php?id_user=<?php echo $id_user?>&b_ref=<?php echo $b_ref?>')
```

Comment: the session is fine now :) thanks but now its still give me `undefined variables function get_booking?` as i included php classes in the header! how do i include the php function in the jquery?

Comment: you should include it in `nav.php` file

Answer (score 0):

1°:

Test your to put `session_start` in the archives `user.inc.php` and `booking.inc.php`.

2°:

HTML:

```
<table id="nav">
<tr>
  <td class="update-ajax"><? include 'pages/nav.php'; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function() {  
        $("#nav tr td.update-ajax").load('pages/nav.php');  // change selector
   }, 5000);  
 });
```